# How to render after an if statement with visual force page

Tags: visualforce, formula, conditional

I have this code

```
<apex:outputText value="{!item['text_1']}" />
<apex:outputText value="{!item['text_2']}" />
```

But `item['text_1']}` could be empty, if this is empty show `text_2`

I tried this code but I get a Syntax Error

```
<apex:outputText value='{!IF({!item["text_1"]} != "", {!item["text_1"]},{!item["text_2"]})}' />
```

Comment: FYI your questions will be much more useful to the community (and might even receive more votes) if you include the actual text of your error messages ***verbatim***.

Comment: Thats the actual error message ` Syntax Error` I use mavensmate with sublime text thats the error who shows me

Answer (score 9):

In this specific case, it would be marginally more efficient to use BLANKVALUE, just as you would with a formula:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!BLANKVALUE(item['text_1'],item['text_2'])}" />
```

A merge expression begins with `{!` and ends with `}`. You do not need to use the syntax recursively. Once you're in "expression mode", you stay there until you exit it with the closing curly brace.

Comment: Ah, nice use of BlankValue method, almost never had got chance to use it. Thanks +1

Answer (score 5):

You can use rendered property to display them conditionally:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!item['text_1']}" rendered="{NOT(ISBLANK(item['text_1']))}"/>
<apex:outputText value="{!item['text_2']}" rendered="{NOT(ISBLANK(item['text_2']))}"/>
```

---

**Added:

Use IF condition along with blank check in value property, here is a correct syntax:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(item['text_1'])), 
    item['text_1'], 
    item['text_2'])}"/>
```